# How to select all columns for rows where I check if just 1 or 2 columns contain duplicate values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having difficulty with what I figure should be an easy problem. I want to select all the columns in a table for which one particular column has duplicate values.

I've been trying to use aggregate functions, but that's constraining me as I want to just match on one column and display all values. Using aggregates seems to require that I 'group by' all columns I'm going to want to display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this should do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable A
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 
             FROM YourTable
             WHERE Col1 = A.Col1
             GROUP BY Col1
             HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can join on a derived table where you aggregate and determine "col" values which are duplicated:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Table1 a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT col
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY col
    HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
) b ON a.col = b.col
```

Answer (score 0):

This query gives you a chance to ORDER BY cola in ascending or descending order and change Cola output.

Here's a Demo on [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/06bb5/1/0).

```
with cl
as
(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by colb order by cola ) as rn
from tbl)

select *
from cl
where rn > 1
```